# Bootstrap fullscreen layout with 100% height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to develop a kiosk-app which should stretch itself to 100% of the complete touch-screen.

When I'm nesting for each application-view/template the rows and cols, it becomes horrible complicated to define every row and every column to set stretch 100% or less (depending on the nested element) in height.

Is there a floating layout for such a case?

### EDIT

Heres some code:

```
<div id="mmenu_screen" class="container-fluid main_container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12" id="mmenu_screen--book">
                    <!-- Button for booking -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12" id="mmenu_screen--information">
                    <!-- Button for information -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 mmenu_screen--direktaction">
            <!-- Button for direktaction -->
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Heres what I want to produce:

```
+------------------------------+small screen
|-------------+ +------------+ |
||            | |            | |
||            | |            | |
||            | |            | |
||            | |            | |
|-------------+ |            | |
|-------------+ |            | |
||            | |            | |
||            | |            | |
||            | |            | |
||            | |            | |
|-------------+ +------------+ |
+------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------+
|----------------------------------------|huge screen
||                  ||                  ||
||                  ||                  ||
||                  ||                  ||
||                  ||                  ||
||                  ||                  ||
||                  ||                  ||
||                  ||                  ||
|--------------------|                  ||
|--------------------|                  ||
||                  ||                  ||
||                  ||                  ||
||                  ||                  ||
||                  ||                  ||
||                  ||                  ||
||                  ||                  ||
|----------------------------------------|
+----------------------------------------+
```

Not something like this (the layout which was looking good on a small screen is now looking to short)

```
+----------------------------------+
|                                  |
| +------------------------------+ |
| |--------------|               | |
| +--------------|               | |
| |             ||               | |
| +------------------------------+ |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question properly. To recap, you have different sections in your web app, and you want each section to stretch to 100% of the viewport height?

Comment: post some code maybe we can help you figure it out also provide the final resolution of your kiosk screen, do you not want to allow scrolling? Maybe a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) is more suited

Comment: Show code or we can't help you.

Comment: Actually I want to add a bunch of elements (buttons, etc.) with a relative height so the layout can stretch over the whole screen without - so some kind of responible but alway looking the same and not rearanging for each screen (a button with 50% height and 50% width placed in top-left on the page should alway take one quarter of the monitor no matter how big the screen is). I will add some code ...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

All you have to do is have a height of 100vh on your main container/wrapper, and then set height 100% or 50% for child elements.. depending on what you're trying to achieve. I tried to copy your mock up in a basic sense.

In case you want to center stuff within, look into flexbox. I put in an example for you.

You can view it on full screen, and resize the browser and see how it works. The layout stays the same.

```css
.left {
  background: grey;  
}

.right {
  background: black;  
}

.main-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;  
}

.section {
  height: 100%;  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.half {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  height: 50%;  
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

h4 {
  color: white;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="section left col-xs-3">
    <div class="half"><h4>Top left</h4></div>
    <div class="half"><h4>Bottom left</h4></div>
  </div>
  <div class="section right col-xs-9">
    <h4>Extra step: center stuff here</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 24):

Here's an answer using the latest **Bootstrap 4.0.0**. This layout is easier using the [flexbox and sizing utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/) that are all provided in Bootstrap 4. This layout is possible with *very* little extra CSS.

```
#mmenu_screen > .row {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.flex-fill {
    flex:1 1 auto;
}

<div id="mmenu_screen" class="container-fluid main_container d-flex">
    <div class="row flex-fill">
        <div class="col-sm-6 h-100">
            <div class="row h-50">
                <div class="col-sm-12" id="mmenu_screen--book">
                    <!-- Button for booking -->
                    Booking
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row h-50">
                <div class="col-sm-12" id="mmenu_screen--information">
                    <!-- Button for information -->
                    Info
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 mmenu_screen--direktaction flex-fill">
            <!-- Button for direktaction -->
            Action
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/1XUBOjCY1Q)

The `flex-fill` and `vh-100` classes are included in Bootstrap 4.1 (and later)

Comment: work excellent for me :::::)))))

Comment: this is good solution but one adjustment. use 100svh instead of 10vh, avoid scroll on mobile

Answer (score 10):

**2021 Sep**
You can set root **div** to viewport fit 100% as well as, say, its child to **predefineds :** 10,25,50,75%

```
    <div class="vh-100">
       <div class="h-50" >
       </div>
    </div>
```

Talking about **Bootstraps 4,5**

Answer (score 2):

If there is no vertical scrolling then you can use `position:absolute` and `height:100%` declared on html and body elements.

Another option is to use viewport height units, see [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window/16837667#16837667)

Absolute position Example:

```css
html, body {
height:100%;
position: absolute;
background-color:red;
}
.button{
  height:50%;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">BUTTON</div>
```

```css
html, body {min-height:100vh;background:gray;
}
.col-100vh {
  height:100vh;
  }
.col-50vh {
  height:50vh;
  }
#mmenu_screen--information{
  background:teal;
}
#mmenu_screen--book{
   background:blue;
}
.mmenu_screen--direktaction{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="mmenu_screen" class="col-100vh container-fluid main_container">

    <div class="row col-100vh">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-100vh">
            
                <div class="col-50vh col-xs-12" id="mmenu_screen--book">
                    BOOKING BUTTON
                </div>
           
                <div class="col-50vh col-xs-12" id="mmenu_screen--information">
                    INFO BUTTON
                </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-100vh col-xs-6 mmenu_screen--direktaction">
           DIRECT ACTION BUTTON
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: this cant work IMO because all the rows and cols are still to small. Even if I declare on each row or col a specific height (which is a lot of work for a more complex template with lots of nested elements) I would have to do this on each template though

Comment: It seems likely that you need to develop a vertical grid system like Bootstrap's horizontal one in order to simplify the development.

Comment: Updated with VH example.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<section class="min-vh-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center py-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
    x
    x
    x
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: please add some details about your solution, just code can not help to find out what is the problem.