# How to make the body tag content to be full screen using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, xcode, twitter-bootstrap, google-web-designer

I am working on a site using bootstrap 5 to code. my issue is i don't know how to make the website to appear on full screen if i view it in my browser.

[website view on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK5m0.png)

Tried this on my CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100vh;
    
    width: 100%;
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap fullscreen layout with 100% height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448221/bootstrap-fullscreen-layout-with-100-height)

Answer (score 1):

Using bootstrap you just need to add `container-fluid` class to your HTML body element.
`<body class="container-fluid">` This will cover entire width of screen.